# How to clean-up an iPhone

Tags: ios, rootkits, firmware

Suppose that an iPhone has been rooted and a back-door installed on the firmware and that this was done in a way that the factory re-start cannot clear out the problems.  How does one clean up this iPhone?  Is there an easy way to wipe the firmware and re-install the original iOS?

How does one securely re-install the firmware and the original iOS?  Suppose that the iPhone has a trojan on it, and attaching the iPhone to a Mac by USB installs the trojan on the computer.  Can someone propose a secure wipe of the iPhone?  Can a Linux machine be used to wipe the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Look up DFU mode - it lets you restore everything without input from the device's OS or firmware.

Comment: You must mean the following? http://www.iphonehacks.com/put-iphone-in-dfu-mode

Comment: An apple discussion link: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5269891?tstart=0

Comment: Yes. DFU mode doesn't let the computer see the system - only gives access to tell the lowest-level firmware of the iDevice to replace its system with a new one.

Comment: Interesting permissions.  It is my understanding that USB trojans install themselves through a peculiarity of the USB protocol during the mounting process.  Are you saying that putting the phone in DFU mode only allows USB access to the firmware and not to the memory?  DFU mode is a software switch, can the access limitations be disabled by changes to the firmware, i.e. if the firmware were cracked by an expert?

Comment: DFU mode doesn't boot (or mount!) the system and instead provides a basic interface (probably from ROM) to write the storage. However, if you are that paranoid, here is another product suggestion: http://goo.gl/Zcy4Mi

Comment: Ha. Ha.  Like the hammer.  It's not paranoia.  I believe I have such a phone.  Perhaps I should smash the thing.

Comment: This seems like a related post: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106122/iphone-5-6-ram-security